# Defining the email address which Nagios sends emails from

Tags: nagios

Hi currently Nagios sends notifications from nagios@server.domain.com, How do I go about configuring this?
Thanks

Answer (score 18):

In a default Nagios install, it's also defined in the `host-notify-by-mail` or `service-notify-by-mail` commands, which you'll find in `commands.cfg`.  The default would be something like:

`/bin/echo -e "$NOTIFICATIONTYPE$  - Service notification for $SERVICEDESC$ from host $HOSTNAME$ - $HOSTALIAS$\n$SERVICEDESC$: $SERVICEOUTPUT$\n" | /bin/mail -s '$NOTIFICATIONTYPE$/$SERVICESTATE$ - $HOSTNAME$/$SERVICEDESC$' $CONTACTEMAIL$`

So just add a `-r sender@address` option to the mail command, and that should work.

Comment: That's what I did, and it worked fine.  Different alerts actually get sent out by different accounts because of our automated ticketing program.

Comment: I added this between `/bin/mail` and the `-s`

Comment: @RainyRat - any chance you can edit your answer to place the -r as first parameter? - as other answers suggest then happy to upvote your answer :o)

Answer (score 3):

Couldn't get the "-- -r nagios@domain.com" solution to work. It turns out options after "--" are options for sendmail. Looking at sendmail options, it should be "-fnagios@domain" NOTE NO SPACE between -f and nagios@domain.com.

So the following is now working :-

```
  command_line    /usr/bin/printf "%b" "Notification Type: $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$\n\nService: $SERVICEDESC$\nHost: $HOSTNAME$\Address: $HOSTADDRESS$\nState: $SERVICESTATE$\n\nDate/Time: $LONGDATETIME$\n\nAdditional Info:\n\n$LONGSERVICEOUTPUT$" | /bin/mail -s "$SERVICESTATE$ - Service Alert: $HOSTALIAS$/$SERVICEDESC$ is $SERVICESTATE$ **" $CONTACTEMAIL$ -- -fnagios@domain.com
```

Answer (score 3):

Put -r nagios@domain before $CONTACTEMAIL$ on commands.cfg

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was adding `-r $ADMINEMAIL$` before the `-s` (immediately after `/bin/mail`), and of course `$ADMINEMAIL$` has to be set in `nagios.cfg` using the `admin_email` setting.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this by changing the command to something liek:

`command_line    /usr/bin/printf "%b" "Notification Type: $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$\n\nService: $SERVICEDESC$\nHost: $HOSTNAME$\Address: $HOSTADDRESS$\nState: $SERVICESTATE$\n\nDate/Time: $LONGDATETIME$\n\nAdditional Info:\n\n$LONGSERVICEOUTPUT$" | /bin/mail -s "$SERVICESTATE$ - Service Alert: $HOSTALIAS$/$SERVICEDESC$ is $SERVICESTATE$ **" $CONTACTEMAIL$ -- -r $ADMINEMAIL$`

The magic is the '-- -r' part.

ADMINEMAIL is set in your nagios.cfg, but could be any email address for the 'From' address.

Answer (score 1):

None of the above works with current versions of Nagios and/or Postfix. The flag that needs to be added to the Nagios "host-notify-by-mail" or "service-notify-by-mail" commands in the file "commands.cfg" reads as follows:

```
-a "From: john.doe@uzh.ch"
```

Note that the quotation marks are essential!

Comment: This changes the From-address, but it does not change the Return-Path address. You may want to change both.

Answer (score 0):

This is defined in `etc/nagios3/conf.d/contacts_nagios2.cfg`

You can define users with e-mails and groups. Also you can configure different groups for different purposes - e.g. web_admin for http alerts, admin for host alerts, etc.

Comment: In the contacts config, you configure the *recipients* of the mails sent, not the *sender* address. This question is about how to change the sender address ("where it sends mails *from*").

Answer (score 0):

For the `bsd-mailx` that my `/usr/bin/mail` command links to, nothing seemed to work, so I used `/usr/sbin/sendmail` (provided by postfix) like this:

```
command_line   /usr/bin/printf "%b" "Subject:** $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$ Host Alert: $HOSTNAME$ is $HOSTSTATE$ **\n\n**** Nagios *****\n\nNotification Type: $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$\nHost: $HOSTNAME$\nState: $HOSTSTATE$\nAddress: $HOSTADDRESS$\nInfo: $HOSTOUTPUT$\n\nDate/Time: $LONGDATETIME$\n" | /usr/sbin/sendmail -r "nagios@example.com" $CONTACTEMAIL$
```

For `sendmail` two things to consider:

- Use  `-r` to specify the return path (and from-address)
- There is no `-s` for the subject. Instead, add the `Subject:` mail header in the `printf` followed by two newlines `\n\n`