# Postfix setup from domain

Tags: postfix, domain, email-bounces

I'm trying to sending email from nagios monitoring to some email addresses. But I have a problem with setup my from domain when I'm sending an email every time my from email address seems like this:

```
from=<root@patrik-VirtualBox>
```

and format like this some mail servers are rejecting.

so I need replace `@patrik-VirtualBox` to my domain `@onedata.sk`

here is my /etc.postfix/main.cf:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
home_mailbox = Maildir/
inet_interfaces = all
mailbox_command =
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = mail.onedata.sk, localhost.localdomain, localhost, yourdomain.com
myhostname = onedata.sk
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
```

from log:

```
Feb  3 01:55:56 patrik-VirtualBox postfix/pickup[10655]: E2FFA66C36: uid=0 from=<root@patrik-VirtualBox>
Feb  3 01:55:56 patrik-VirtualBox postfix/cleanup[10963]: E2FFA66C36: message-id=<20150203005556.E2FFA66C36@onedata.sk>
Feb  3 01:55:56 patrik-VirtualBox postfix/qmgr[10656]: E2FFA66C36: from=<root@patrik-VirtualBox>, size=340, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb  3 01:56:35 patrik-VirtualBox postfix/smtp[10965]: E2FFA66C36: to=<patrik.kristel@onedata.sk>, relay=mailhub.nextra.sk[195.168.1.42]:25, delay=38, delays=0.03/0.01/30/8, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (host mailhub.nextra.sk[195.168.1.42] said: 517 Syntax error. (in reply to MAIL FROM command))
```

I have also tried to set up `relayhost` or [this topic](https://serverfault.com/questions/522503/postfix-holds-email-from-domain), but it didn't help.

I have configured it in another server like this and there it works fine, so I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: It's not postfix fault, the sender was set by nagios. See this question [Defining the email address which Nagios sends emails from](http://serverfault.com/questions/73004/defining-the-email-address-which-nagios-sends-emails-from)

Comment: it is not issue with Nagios, I'm trying to send email like root at first, e.g.:
`root@patrik-VirtualBox:~# echo "test" | mail -s "test mail" patrik.kristel@onedata.sk` and it is rejected because the from email address is `root@patrik-VirtualBox`

Comment: Set your server hostname to FQDN one. **Postfix doesn't set the sender address**, it was set by nagios/mail command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by changing the `/etc/hostname` configuration file:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/158957/how-to-set-the-fully-qualified-domain-name-in-12-04

Answer (score 0):

Nagios just uses /usr/bin/mail (by default). You can change the args that are passed to the mail binary; it's just a single line in the notification command definition.

You can change the from address by adding something like `-- -f nagios@onedata.sk` to the end of the line. This will cause the -f to be passed to sendmail, to set the 'envelope from' address.

(In Debian/Ubuntu, this is done in /etc/nagios3/commands.cfg. I'm not sure about other distro packages.)

Answer (score -1):

Set your domain in

```
/etc/mailname
```

Then restart postfix

```
/etc/init.d/postfix restart
```

Then, try again.

Comment: it was already set there..

Comment: /etc/mailname [only affected envelope sender](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#append_at_myorigin) if mail addresses have no domain information.